# str() is not usable anymore to get true value of a Text tfx.data_types.RuntimeParameter during pipeline execution

Tags: kubeflow, tfx

how to get string as true value of `tfx.orchestration.data_types.RuntimeParameter` during execution pipeline?

Hi,

I'm defining a runtime parameter like `data_root = tfx.orchestration.data_types.RuntimeParameter(name='data-root', ptype=str)` for a base path, from which I define many subfolders for various components like `str(data_root)+'/model'` for model serving path in `tfx.components.Pusher()`.

It was working like a charm before I moved to `tfx==1.12.0`: `str(data_root)` is now providing a json dump.
To overcome that, i tried to define a runtime parameter for model path like `model_root = tfx.orchestration.data_types.RuntimeParameter(name='model-root', ptype=str)` and then feed the `Pusher` component the way I saw in many tutotrials:

```
pusher = Pusher(model=trainer.outputs['model'],
                model_blessing=evaluator.outputs['blessing'],
                push_destination=tfx.proto.PushDestination(
                    filesystem=tfx.proto.PushDestination.Filesystem(base_directory=model_root)))
```

but I get a `TypeError` saying `tfx.proto.PushDestination.Filesystem` does not accept `Runtime` parameter.

It completely breaks the existing setup as i received those parameters from external client for each kubeflow run.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it.

First of all, the docstring is not clear regarding which parameter of `Pusher` can be a `RuntimeParameter` or not.
I finally went to `__init__` code definition of component `Pusher` to see that only the parameter `push_destination` can be a `RuntimeParameter`:

```
  def __init__(
      self,
      model: Optional[types.BaseChannel] = None,
      model_blessing: Optional[types.BaseChannel] = None,
      infra_blessing: Optional[types.BaseChannel] = None,
      push_destination: Optional[Union[pusher_pb2.PushDestination,
                                       data_types.RuntimeParameter]] = None,
      custom_config: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
      custom_executor_spec: Optional[executor_spec.ExecutorSpec] = None):
```

Then I defined the component consequently, using my `RuntimeParameter`

```
model_root = tfx.orchestration.data_types.RuntimeParameter(name='model-serving-location', ptype=str)
pusher = Pusher(model=trainer.outputs['model'],
                model_blessing=evaluator.outputs['blessing'],
                push_destination=model_root)
```

As `push_destination` parameter is supposed to be message proto `tfx.proto.pusher_pb2.PushDestination`, you have then to respect the associated schema when instantiating and running a pipeline execution, meaning the `value` should be like:

```
{'type': 'model-serving-location': 'value': '{"filesystem": {"base_directory": "path/to/model/serving/for/the/run"}}'}
```

Regards